# Using exception handling to break from While loop in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I'm writing a program manipulating iterators in python3. 
While looking online, I encountered a (pretty) strange solution to the problem of iterating from a random value in the middle to the last value  that looks something like this:

```
next(it) # X4 times, for example

while True:
        try:
           #some code
           next(it)

        except StopIteration:
            break
```

I was wondering if there is another way of implementing this kind of code. because using exception handling to break from a loop looks a bit odd to me?

Comment: You could use a for loop instead: `for item in it:`

Comment: but will it work if I already skipped some iterations? (i.e called next on it few times)

Comment: @MichaelS Yes it will.

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried this out :)